# Add hover event ( cursor pointer property) to body but not to its children

Tags: jquery, css, hover

code example:

```
<body>
    <div id="something" style="width: 50vw; height: 300px;">
        </div>
    <div class="else">oekdoekod</div>
</body>
```

the problem is that I need to have cursor pointer effect only when hovering body, NOT hovering the `div` with `id="something"`.

it doesn't work

```
:not(#something) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

but

```
$(document.body).on("hover", ":not(#something, #something *)",function(e){ 
   $(this).addClass("pointer"); 
     e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

with css

```
.pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

it works but only on other elements e.g. `.else`

How can I apply `pointer` cursor on `hover` event only on body but not on `#something`?

Comment: Use an * before your css *:not(#something) { cursor: pointer; }

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, what browser are you testing this in? Here is the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/pagefa/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output).

**CSS**

```
body{
  cursor:crosshair;

}

#something {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 300px;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,255,.2);
  cursor:pointer;
}

#else{
  width: 50vw;
  height: 300px;
  background-color:rgba(0,255,255,.2);
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="something"></div>
<div id="else"></div>
```

Comment: IT WORKS!! it was so easy THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description to have a pointer cursor on body and NOT #something, this should do the trick:

```
body {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#something {
    cursor: auto;
}
```